# Device spoofing, instead of MAC address spoofing

Tags: anonymity, tails, deanonymization, spoofing

Besides **MAC address spoofing**, how can device name, device brand, and device type spoofing (randomization?) be done on a Tails (windows) system, so that WLAN hotspot hosts see different information than what the device actually is?

It says Tails [automatically spoofs](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/welcome_screen/mac_spoofing/index.en.html) the user's MAC address, but how can the MAC address spoof be

- **monitored** (i.e. proved by visiting a MAC address self-lookup site, like how people do IP address lookup on themselves), and
- **customized** (i.e. so that the user can be in control of what Tails will set the spoofed device name and manufacturer to, instead of Tails automatically deciding by itself)?

Comment: Device manufacturer is determined from the first three octets of the MAC address, Sppof the MAC as a local address or as another manufacturer.

Comment: yeah how can the manufacturer be spoofed

Comment: By spoofing the MAC address to a different vendor and/or to a local address. See: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html & https://standards.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-standards/standards/web/documents/tutorials/macgrp.pdf

Comment: Tails automatically spoofs the MAC address doesn't it? Instead of automatically, how can the Tails user exert control over which manufacturer Tails sets it to? https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/welcome_screen/mac_spoofing/index.en.html